# How to get all the json keys in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a JSON object that has the following structure

```
{"30-31":[{"msg":"hello","usr":"31"}],
"33-30":[{"msg":"shah hi","usr":"30"}]}
```

What operation can I perform to get an array like this `["30-31", "33-30"]`.
I tried my best using `.map` etc but with no success, can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in `Object.keys(obj)` that you can use:

```js
var json = {"30-31":[{"msg":"hello","usr":"31"}],
            "33-30":[{"msg":"shah hi","usr":"30"}]};
var keys = Object.keys(json);
console.log(keys);
```

Additionally, you can do it the hard (cross-browser) way with a `for...in` loop:

```js
var json = {"30-31":[{"msg":"hello","usr":"31"}],
            "33-30":[{"msg":"shah hi","usr":"30"}]};
var keys = [];
for (k in json) keys.push(k);
console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
let obj = {"30-31":[{"msg":"hello","usr":"31"}],
  "33-30":[{"msg":"shah hi","usr":"30"}]}
  
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```